# Consider 70 digit numbers n with the property that each of the digits 1,2,3,...,7 appears in the decimal expansion of n ten times

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Consider 70 digit numbers n with the property that each of the digits 1,2,3,...,7 appears in the decimal expansion of n ten times (and 8,9,0 do not appear). Show that no number of this form can divide another number of this form.

My attempt:
I really couldn't think anything at all except for trying (mod 3) and (mod 5) but nothing seemed to be useful and on the other hand came across the fact that suppose $$a|b$$ if a ends in odd digit and b in even digit then it's not possible.

Comment: Hint: try mod $9$ (think about digital roots).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say we had $a$ and $b$ in this set such that $b=ka$ for some $k>1$.

The smallest member of the set starts with a string of ten $1$s, then ten $2$s, etc; the largest with a string of ten $7$s; so $1<k<7$.

All of these numbers have the same digit sum, namely $280$; hence each number is congruent to $1$ modulo $9$. We must have $k\equiv 1\pmod 9$; but no $1<k<7$ satisfies this; contradiction.